# Как написать - df["revenue"][counter]=addr, чтобы интерпретатор не выдавал ошибки?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, обработка-данных

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("logs.tsv",sep='\t')
df.head(19)

df.buy_ts=pd.to_datetime(df.buy_ts)
df.visit_ts=pd.to_datetime(df.visit_ts)
df.dtypes

counter=0
for addr in df["revenue"].to_list():
    addr=addr[1:]
    addr=addr.replace(" ","")
    addr=addr.replace(",",".")
    addr=float(addr)
    df["revenue"][counter]=addr
    counter=counter+1
```

Comment: Всё работает но интерпретатор подсвечивает красным и выдает <ipython-input-2-adb5f76b4c42>:15: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  df["revenue"][counter]=addr

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

попробуйте так:

```
df.loc[counter, "revenue"] = addr
```

а еще лучше заменить весь цикл на векторизированное решение:

```
df["revenue"] = \
    pd.to_numeric(df["revenue"]
                    .str[1:]
                    .replace([r"\s", ","], ["", "."], regex=True), 
                  errors="coerce")
```

**DISCLAIMER:** данное решение не тестировалось, т.к. в вопросе отсутствует воспроизводимый пример данных и ожидаемый результат

PS возможно вам будет достаточно указать параметры: `pd.read_csv(..., thousands=" ", decimal=",")`, но для того, чтобы сказать точно нужен пример нескольких строк исходного CSV файла.